# How to get a full party?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am looking for good ways to get a full party in public games.

A full party is important because I heard that rare drops drop more often when you have a full 4 player party.

What quests on what difficulties would be a good place to start to get all 3 players needed to get the wanted full party?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there are some load balancing issues on Blizzard's end making it difficult for a full party to form through public games, but your best bet is to hang out at the beginning of a quest for a little while, as that's where the game tries and puts players joining public games, and you will generally(perhaps never) get a public player joining mid-quest line.

Once the issues with Blizzard's servers are resolved, I imagine it will be much easier to form a full party.

Also, the source of the information for the load balancing issue was a forum post by a Blizzard Developer, which I'm having trouble finding.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the obvious suggestion of playing with your real life friends, I'd be amiss to not suggest playing with your [internet friends](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4649/are-you-playing-diablo-3-why-dont-you-play-with-us)?

If you can't get a full group of four between your friends, if you can get one or two other friends together, you should have a better chance of finding a fourth in a public lobby.

Comment: Good plug there Dave. Good plug.

Comment: @Fredy31 I do what I can